# When launch android application using android studio,App have terminated after using drawable images

Tags: android, android-studio

```
10/15 06:24:08: Launching 'app' on HUAWEI CRO-U00.
$ adb shell am start -n "com.example.beautifulsrilanka/com.example.beautifulsrilanka.MainActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
Connected to process 23728 on device 'huawei-cro_u00-CAX9K17A23902962'.
Capturing and displaying logcat messages from application. This behavior can be disabled in the "Logcat output" section of the "Debugger" settings page.
I/art: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.example.beautifulsrilanka-1/lib/arm
W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter androidx.vectordrawable.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<androidx.core.view.ViewCompat$OnUnhandledKeyEventListenerWrapper>
    Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<androidx.core.view.ViewCompat$OnUnhandledKeyEventListenerWrapper>
D/skia: jpeg_decoder mode 1, colorType 4, w 5152, h 3864, sample 1, bsLength 21b621!!
D/skia: jpeg_decoder finish successfully, L:1919!!!
I/art: Starting a blocking GC Alloc
    Starting a blocking GC Alloc
I/art: Alloc sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 4483(435KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 26% free, 4MB/5MB, paused 540us total 41.391ms
    Starting a blocking GC Alloc
I/System: FinalizerDaemon: finalize objects = 1
I/art: Alloc partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 229(23KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 24% free, 4MB/5MB, paused 407us total 10.815ms
I/art: Starting a blocking GC Alloc
I/art: Alloc concurrent mark sweep GC freed 19(12KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 24% free, 4MB/5MB, paused 460us total 18.883ms
    Forcing collection of SoftReferences for 170MB allocation
    Starting a blocking GC Alloc
I/art: Alloc concurrent mark sweep GC freed 11(344B) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 24% free, 4MB/5MB, paused 436us total 16.672ms
W/art: Throwing OutOfMemoryError "Failed to allocate a 179165964 byte allocation with 1414341 free bytes and 123MB until OOM"
I/art: Starting a blocking GC Alloc
    Starting a blocking GC Alloc
I/art: Alloc sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 3(592B) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 24% free, 4MB/5MB, paused 415us total 6.482ms
    Starting a blocking GC Alloc
I/art: Alloc partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 6(192B) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 24% free, 4MB/5MB, paused 588us total 8.391ms
    Starting a blocking GC Alloc
I/art: Alloc concurrent mark sweep GC freed 3(96B) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 24% free, 4MB/5MB, paused 437us total 16.209ms
I/art: Forcing collection of SoftReferences for 170MB allocation
    Starting a blocking GC Alloc
I/art: Alloc concurrent mark sweep GC freed 3(96B) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 24% free, 4MB/5MB, paused 452us total 16.016ms
W/art: Throwing OutOfMemoryError "Failed to allocate a 179165964 byte allocation with 1414341 free bytes and 123MB until OOM"
D/skia: --- allocation failed for scaled bitmap
D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 23728 SIG: 9
Process 23728 terminated.
```

Comment: I see you out memory. you can you lib load image or resize image.

Comment: @QuestionAndroid,thanks,that was the problem,before add to drable folder I resized them and worked